# PHP passing arguments from bash. How can I use foreach starting from [2]?

Tags: php

I am passing some arguments to a PHP file from bash. Current code is working fine:

```
foreach($argv as $value)
{
$a= $a . "\n" . $value;
}
```

However I am looking for a way to start the foreach from the 3rd item of the array (which is variable so I don't know how many arguments the script will receive). Any ideas on how I can skip the first 3 elements?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use array_slice.

Comment: Works great thanks!

`foreach(array_slice($argv,3) as $value){
$a= $a . "\n" . $value;
}`